# Manage Tags is loading a blank page

Tags: drupal, error, tags

When a staff or admin goes to manage tags, the page doesn't seem to load anything. I have checked in Drupal permissions that both admins and staff have permissions to administer tags and tag sets (in `https://www.fosterclub.com/civicrm/tag?reset=1` or Contacts > Manage Tags).

I checked the following logs and can't seem to find anything related:

- CiviCRM `sites/default/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog` latest log
- Apache
- MySQL
- Drupal (I use Drupal syslog in `/var/log/drupal` instead of watchdog)

I have checked in my development environment and the issue doesn't exist, and no code changes have been made or tracked through git.

Has anyone heard of this issue or know what I should try or look for? Thanks!

Edit: Other pages that seem to be affected:

- New Tag
- New Activity
- Payment Processor settings

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused from the oldest problem in the book. I needed to delete the everything inside `sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c` and then clear caches and make it writeable (chmod `775`).

That solved all of the above mentioned page load issues.

We had recently restored the website from an older backup and this always needs to be done when moving or refreshing CiviCRM on the server.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar problem to this, but with a different solution. Thought I'd document it here. Manage Tags was failing to load with a *nearly* blank page. [image: Manage tags failure to load] but the problem turned out to be a malformed date in the created_date field of the 'tags' table. one date was set to 000-00-00 00:00:00 (don't ask me how, I don't know). Setting this field to any valid date corrected the problem.